# jsx syntax that confuses me

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I saw the next code:

```
const cardSource = {
  beginDrag(props) {
    return {
      text: props.text
    };
  }
};
```

Typically I use {} for jsx block code or to build objects. cardSource makes me feel uneasy. Is  beginDrag  a member of cardSource? If so, can I use the call:  cardSource.beginDrag()?

Comment: Yes, you most definitely can!

Comment: This is ES6, not JSX. It's a shorter way of `beginDrag: function(props) { ... }` And if you use that call without passing the props, it will generate a null pointer error.

Answer (score 1):

> Is beginDrag a member of cardSource?

Yes.  This is equivalent to :

```
const cardSource = {
  beginDrag: function beginDrag(props) {
    return {
      text: props.text
    };
  }
};
```

> If so, can I use the call: cardSource.beginDrag()?

Yes.